# get html element value after changing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a view, I'm trying to retrieve the value of an html input box AFTER I have changed it. In other words, the page loads with

```
<input id="input_one" type="text" value = "apple" />
```

When the page opens the input box has the word apple in it. I click on this input box, erase the word apple, and then write the word "orange" in instead. when I do the following:

```
$('#input_one').click(function() {
    console.log($('#input_one').attr('value'));
});
```

the result is "apple" not orange. Is there a way to get the new value I just input without submitting the form? I'm trying to make client side validation using javascript on the page, if the value is something, submit form, otherwise display message "value must be something"

maybe I can do something like

```
 $('#input_one').attr('value', 'new value');
```

but how do I get the new value I just put in? where is this new value stored? innerHTML? or text() maybe?

Comment: You should look into the [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method.

Comment: cool thanks, looking into it now

Comment: @Asik thank you for pointing that out, I already have a .click event, forgot to include it.

Comment: @both, thanks..I have removed my comment..

Comment: @Asik you didn't have to remove it, it was my fault, forgot to include the right info

Comment: Anyway, Others understand better than me..anyway no issues..thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attr()` will get the *attribute* of the `<input>`, which is the *initial* value of the element.

The current value of the element is a *property*. If we wanted to get any element property:

```
$('#input_one')[0].value;    
$('#input_one').prop('value');
```

*However,* jQuery has the perfect method, [`.val()`,](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for you:

```
$('#input_one').val();
```

---

[*What is the difference between attribute and property?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10673539/1612146)

Answer (score 1):

Try `.val()` instead:

```
$('#input_one').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("#input_one").blur(function() {
   alert(this.value); 
});
```

This alerts the new value of the input box every time you put it out of focus.