# PHP json_encode returning empty sctructure

Tags: php, json

I'm calling json_encode to sendo a objects array back to the user, and at other parts of my code it works properly, but at this one it return a empty structure string.

Here is the result when I call json_encode on the array before encoding:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(MinaProxy)#5 (7) {
    ["carregado":"MinaProxy":private]=>
    bool(true)
    ["link":"MinaProxy":private]=>
    int(1)
    ["idMina":protected]=>
    int(1)
    ["qntOuro":protected]=>
    int(2000)
    ["x":protected]=>
    int(307)
    ["idPartida":protected]=>
    int(1)
    ["proximo":protected]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(MinaProxy)#6 (7) {
    ["carregado":"MinaProxy":private]=>
    bool(true)
    ["link":"MinaProxy":private]=>
    int(2)
    ["idMina":protected]=>
    int(2)
    ["qntOuro":protected]=>
    int(2000)
    ["x":protected]=>
    int(512)
    ["idPartida":protected]=>
    int(1)
    ["proximo":protected]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [2]=>
  object(MinaProxy)#7 (7) {
    ["carregado":"MinaProxy":private]=>
    bool(true)
    ["link":"MinaProxy":private]=>
    int(3)
    ["idMina":protected]=>
    int(3)
    ["qntOuro":protected]=>
    int(2000)
    ["x":protected]=>
    int(716)
    ["idPartida":protected]=>
    int(1)
    ["proximo":protected]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Here is the result after json_encode:

```
[{},{},{}]
```

As can be noticed, there is no special characters in the original array, so I do not think it is a encoding issue.
Here is the code where I call json_encode:

```
elseif($dados['acao'] == 'recuperarMinas') {
    $i = 0;
    $array = array();
    while ($this->partida->minas->temProximo()) {
        $array[$i] = $this->partida->minas->getProximoAvancando();
        $array[$i]->getIdPartida();
        $i++;
    }
    $_SESSION['partida'] = $this->partida;
    $retornoJson = json_encode($array);
    return $retornoJson;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have protected and private attributes, so you can not use any functions, including json_encode() to access directly to your object's property.

Use [JSONSerialize](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php)

Answer (score 5):

Problem is that your output has three Objects with private and protected attributes.

See this example

```
<?php

class sampleClass
{
    private $hello = 25;
}


$class = new sampleClass();

echo json_encode($class);

?>
```

Output will be {}

In your case you have array [] of three {} objects, and they are empty because all their attributes are private or protected.

But if you will change object attributes to be public, `public $hello = 25;` then output will be

```
{"hello":25}
```

Comment: @Andreas my first answer in stackoverflow ))

Comment: (I meant you came first answering this particular question)

Comment: @user777 just realized that you 've written method you meant properties/attributes isn't it? ;)

Comment: After thinking about properties/attributes I landed on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258469/what-is-the-difference-between-attribute-and-property). Dear Lord ....!! SO is always fun!

Comment: Coming from Java, this was a nightmare ! But totally logical !

Answer (score 0):

It's because they are not public If you want json_encode private/protected variables you have to implement JSON serialization your self.

You could try considering [jsonserializable](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php) (php 5.4+)with caution!!!!!!!
Lets say that you want to serialize private/protected properties of your objects in your response to some http requests but in other cases you may not want these properties to be serialized or you may already run code(even third party) that assumes they are not

anyhow if you want to expose all your  object's properties the code in your fuction could be something like this:

```
public function somethinghere() {
    return get_object_vars($this);
}
```

The full signature  of the function was left out in purpose because you should decide what you want to do according to your context(I was having considerations before posting this but I hope this way criticism will be minimized ) This example may also be considered as bad because it exposes everything(you may consider creating an associative array that contain only the properties you want to expose )

[working example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/186860cf88f91c9fe093)