# How can I base a cells colspan on a conditional value using angular?

Tags: html, angularjs, conditional-statements, html-table, inline

Based on a value elsewhere on the html page I need a row within a table to show more cells then everywhere else in the table.  In order to keep alignments correct and everything clean I am looking for a way to dynamically set the colspan of a cell using angular.  I just can't seem to get this working.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.noInventory"/>

<table>  
  <th>
     <td>Product</td>
     <td colspan={{vm.noInventory ? '2' : '1'}}>Inventory<td>
     <td ng-show="vm.noInventory"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Product B</td>
     <td>55 parts</td>
     <td ng-show="vm.noInventory">Backordered</td>      
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 19):

Found the solution... I actually had a typo and needed to include "" in the colspan...

```
<td colspan="{{vm.noInventory ? '2' : '1'}}">Inventory<td>
```

Comment: Thanks! With Angular 2 I'm doing in this way: ``[attr.colspan]="isTrueValue ? '2' : '0'"``

Answer (score 11):

If you are working in angular where table rows are dynamically generated you can use following 
`<td [attr.colspan]="fieldsChanged.fieldName == 'Comments' ? '2' : ''">                                {{fieldsChanged.newValue}}</td>`

Answer (score 1):

Another method if you are ok with setting colspan through CSS would be to leverage [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) and define a function which returns an object similar to the one you specified inline.

For example you could add the ng-style directive to the TD element like below:

```
<td ng-style=vm.colWidth(vm.noInventory)>Inventory<td>
```

And in your JS:

```
vm.colWidth = function(noInv) {
  return  {"colspan": noInv ? '2' : '1' };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having issues getting this to work, the top comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35615751/why-is-colspan-not-a-known-native-attribute-in-angular-2) post helped. In the end I used `[colSpan]="holdingsData.fund.entity[0].ticker ? '2' : '1'"`obviously enter your own variable and it should do the trick.