# How to use property binding with td attribute colspan in angular?

Tags: angular

I was working on table element in angular. Al through my code works fine. But when I need to implement property binding on `td` attribute `colspan` its showing me below error in browser console:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
  Can't bind to 'colspan' since it isn't a known property of 'td'. ("Total Rows:
                    </td>
                    <td [ERROR ->]colspan="{{count}}">
                      {{rows}}
                    </td>
```

**What I've tried is:**

```
<table class="table table-hover" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
            {{col}}
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of getFilteredData">
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
            {{data[col]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="{{count}}">
            Total Rows: {{rows}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**What I want:**

[image]

In my .ts file I give `count` value to the length of columns array so what ever the columns length are my footer cell have equally distributed using property binding.

I also try:

- [colspan]="count"
- colspan="'count'"

but none of this worked and showing the same error.

Comment: Did you try `[attr.colspan]="count"`?

Comment: have you tried " **[colSpan]"** ? mentionned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35615751/why-is-colspan-not-a-known-native-attribute-in-angular-2/35616510

Comment: you can use [colSpan]="..." since the DOM calls it colSpan and not colspan

Answer (score 224, accepted):

try this,

If you want to bind to an attribute use `[attr.colspan]="count"` syntax

Here, colspan is not a property of td element. colspan is an attribute. so we have to add prefix attr to colspan to tell angular that it is an attribute if we not write attr prefix then angular consider it property so it will throw error.

Comment: Now its working perfectly.

Comment: @Hoang Tran Son It's my pleasure

Comment: Be aware that binding to attributes can be [unnecessarily expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35619455/1697459)

Comment: Seems that the newest version of Angular (12.2.1) does not like binding to colspan with quotes so what worked for me was:

[attr.colspan]=count