# PrimeNg TurboTable colgroup dynamic colspan

Tags: angular5, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-turbotable

How can I assign variable to primeng TurboTable ColGroup colspan property.

```
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="3">Brand</th>
        <th colspan="4">Sale Rate</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="colSpanCount">Sales</th>
        <th colspan="2">Profits</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Last Year</th>
        <th>This Year</th>
        <th>Last Year</th>
        <th>This Year</th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

In above example, I want to bind colSpanCount variable to colspan attribute of p-table.

Answer (score 5):

I think, I have found an answer myself. We can set [attr.colspan]="colSpanCount" property to set colspan dynamically.

```
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="3">Brand</th>
        <th colspan="4">Sale Rate</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th [attr.colspan]="colSpanCount">Sales</th>
        <th colspan="2">Profits</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Last Year</th>
        <th>This Year</th>
        <th>Last Year</th>
        <th>This Year</th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, you can change `colspan` to `[attr.colspan]`.

Another solution is to change `colspan` to `[colSpan]`.

[See this answer for a deeper explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35615751/why-is-colspan-not-a-known-native-attribute-in-angular-2)