# Angular2 maxLength for textarea as variable

Tags: variables, angular, textarea

To set max letters number for textarea, we do achieve that by writing:
`<textarea maxLength="50"></textarea>`

but, could I do something like below? Is there some way?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-create-offer-page',
  template: `
    <textarea maxLength="textareaLength"></textarea>
  `
})
export class CreateOfferPageComponent {
  textareaLength: number = 50;
}
```

I'm asking because that does not work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You would need `[]` for Angular to interpret it as binding

```
 [maxLength]="textareaLength"
```

This should work for native validation. Angular2 validators don't currently support dynamic values.

Comment: Thank you. It works like a charm but I notice that attr.maxLength works aswell. Is there some good practice to add attr. before attributes?

Comment: `maxLength` is a native attribute and thus can directly be bound with `[maxLength]`. If you want to set a custom attribute like `data-id` for example, you can use the binding with `[attr.data-id]`. In the end it doesn't make a difference for those native attributes.

Comment: I see! Thank you for your help. Have a nice day.

Comment: If it doesn't work without `[attr.` then add it ;-). Most properties are reflected to the DOM so if you set the property, the attribute gets created and vice versa. For others this doesn't work like for example `<lable for="....">` doesn't work because the property name is `htmlFor` and the attribute name is for. If it is an `@Input()` of a custom component or directive and you don't need it on the DOM (for example to use it for CSS selectors) then it's better to not add `[attr.` because it means adding to the DOM which is much slower than property only.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258469/what-is-the-difference-between-attribute-and-property

Answer (score 18):

Expanding a little bit on the answer provided by [@rinukkusu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38249081/2730233), you could even make the attribute optional by adding a ternary operator, like so:

```html
<textarea [attr.maxLength]="textareaLength > 0 ? textareaLength : null"></textarea>
```

The `null` value removes the attribute completely from the element, which was something I needed.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Sure and it's pretty easy - just use attribute binding like so:

```html
<textarea [attr.maxLength]="textareaLength"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I regret that I can't accept two answers but u were late about 9 seconds. But of course, point for you :)