# Max Length for Each Line in Textarea

Tags: angular, typescript, textarea, line, maxlength

I use Angular 5.2.6 and adding some form file in my html.
There is a textarea in that form and I want to limit its maximum chars in each row.

Here is the HTML part:

```
<textarea siInput [(ngModel)]="myTextarea" style="resize:none;  white-space: nowrap;" rows="20" (ngModelChange)="`handleTextareaChange`($event)" (keydown)="onKeydown($event)" maxlength="{{maxlength}}" id="textID"></textarea>
```

I have defined **maxlength** and **maxLineLength** in component class.
Also here is the methods I have tried so far :)

```
onKeydown(event) {
   if (event.key === "Enter") {
     this.pressEnter = true;
     this.maxlength += this.maxLineLength + 1;
   }
   else {
     this.pressEnter = false;
   }
}

handleTextareaChange(text) {

   var mainString = text;
   var allLines = mainString.split("\n");

   var len = mainString.length;
   var numberOfLines = allLines.length;
   var indexOfCurrentLine = allLines.length - 1;

   var previousLines = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < indexOfCurrentLine; i++) {
     previousLines += allLines[i];
   }
}
```

If you have any ideas, please share with me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. I did not use maxlength properties, and created new function in component.ts

here is HTML:

```
<textarea siInput [(ngModel)]="myTextarea" style="resize:none;  white-space: both;" rows="20" (keyup)="onKeyAction()"(keydown)="onKeyAction()" id="textID" maxlength="{{maxTextAreaLength}}"></textarea>
```

and here is the funtion in component:

```
this.maxTextLineLength: number = 50;
onKeyAction() {
    if (this.myTextarea) {
      var lines = this.myTextarea.split(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm);
      for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (lines[i].length >= this.maxTextLineLength) {
          lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, this.maxTextLineLength);
        }
      }
      this.myTextarea = lines.join('');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution for control in maxlength,

you have to pass like this in your textarea tag,

```
[maxLength]="textareaLength"
```

either you can use like this also,

```
[attr.maxlength]="maxLength"
```

you can set this variable value in typescript,

For more Reference,

[Angular2 maxLength for textarea as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249022/angular2-maxlength-for-textarea-as-variable)

http://embed.plnkr.co/CkAbaQLQVndoC47OtQRF/

I hope it's solve your problem.

Comment: I have already used as maxlength="{{maxlength}}" :) I want to limit for each row... When enter key is used (new line), it can be typed again in that new line