# Difference between binding the attributes with [attr.attributeName] and [attributeName] in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

When I bind attributes, I used to do it like this:

Example1:

```
  <input type="number" [max]="variableName">
```

Example2:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
  <option *ngFor="let item of itemList" [value]="item.value" [selected]="selectedItem==item.value">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Sometimes, these bindings would fail.

But, when I use the following syntax to bind attributes (by suffixing attribute name with attr.):

Example1:

```
<input type="number" [attr.max]="variableName">
```

Example2:

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
      <option *ngFor="let item of itemList" [value]="item.value" [attr.selected]="selectedItem==item.value">{{item.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

With this syntax, it worked like charm sometimes.

What is the difference between `[attributename]` and `[attr.attributeName]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is property binding

```
[selected]="selectedItem==item.value"
```

This is attribute binding

```
[attr.selected]="selectedItem==item.value"
```

See also [What is the difference between attribute and property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258469/what-is-the-difference-between-attribute-and-property) for the difference between property and attribute.

Property binding works only if the element actually has a property with that name. Some property are automatically reflected to attributes.

Attribute just adds an attribute with that name to the DOM element. Known attributes are read by elements (and `@Input()`s of Angular components). 
Custom attributes are just added to the DOM and not processed by the element.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info.