# How can I set an Input object of type checkbox as required inside my javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following inside of our third part application, where I can write custom javascript or jquery code against the web pages, but I can not modify the markup:

```
<input id="OrderLiveOrder_0e0052d6-9924-4774-b50d-d7ef364d744a_MultiChoiceOption_0" type="checkbox">
```

I am trying to set the above input field, which is of type checkbox, as required now ( so I need to make sure that the user check the checkbox  ). I tried this:

```
$('input[id^="OrderLiveOrder_"]').required;
```

based on this link https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_required.asp but it did not apply the validation. I also tried this:

```
 $('input[id^="OrderLiveOrder_"]').required = true;
```

but it did not fix the issue. So, can anyone advice on this?

Comment: try something like `$('input[id^="OrderLiveOrder_"]').attr("required",true)`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen this will add an attribute to my input field such as follow `required="required"` but there is no validation that has been applied to the field

Comment: Please edit by adding your ERP background explanations. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `prop`

```
$('input[id^="OrderLiveOrder_"]').prop("required", true);
```

or (also) by `attr`

```
$('input[id^="OrderLiveOrder_"]').attr("required", true);
```

Comment: Try `$('input[id^="OrderLiveOrder_"]').attr("required", "required")` as well, and share a working snippet that demonstrate your issue.

Comment: now using `$('input[id^="OrderLiveOrder_"]').prop("required", true);` will modify the markup as follow `<input id="OrderLiveOrder_0e0052d6-9924-4774-b50d-d7ef364d744a_MultiChoiceOption_0" type="checkbox" required="required">` but did not add any validation. now one note i have is that the 3rd party application do not use HTML-5  could this be the reason ?

Comment: @johnG It is difficult to tell without a working snippet.. please share the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use `attr("required",true)` to set the `required` attribute of all the elements(in your case, checkbox) to `true` by using `input[id^="OrderLiveOrder_"]` query selector. To check the working of the below snippet you can use the browser's `inspect element` option on that `checkbox`.

```js
$('input[id^="OrderLiveOrder_"]').attr("required",true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' id='OrderLiveOrder_1'>1
<input type='checkbox' id='OrderLiveOrder_2'>2
<input type='checkbox' id='OrderLiveOrder_3'>3
```

Comment: now using `$('input[id^="OrderLiveOrder_"]').attr("required",true);` will modify the markup as follow `<input id="OrderLiveOrder_0e0052d6-9924-4774-b50d-d7ef364d744a_MultiChoiceOption_0" type="checkbox" required="required">`but did not add any validation. now one note i have is that the 3rd party application do not use HTML-5 could this be the reason ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use both `prop` or `attr` to set the `input` as `required`.

Here is your `input` inside a working snippet:
(Try it by submitting before ticking the checkbox)

```js
$('input[id^="OrderLiveOrder_"]').prop("required", true);
console.log($('input[id^="OrderLiveOrder_"]').attr("required"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input id="OrderLiveOrder_0e0052d6-9924-4774-b50d-d7ef364d744a_MultiChoiceOption_0" type="checkbox">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

`prop` and `attr` are basically the same.
Check the answer here: [What is the difference between attribute and property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258469/what-is-the-difference-between-attribute-and-property)

Comment: now your script will add the following attribute to the input field `required="required"` but did not add any validation..

Comment: @johnG What other validation do you need? The form can't be send if the checkbox is not ticked by the user. That's what you wanted according to your question.

Comment: @johnG So… done. :) Try not to check and submit the form in my snippet. It won't!

Comment: now in my case i am working on an ERP system which is a bit old, so not sure if it will understand something as follow `$('input[id^="OrderLiveOrder_"]').prop("required", true);` as usually inside the ERP system i can define a field as required from the the beginning using the admin screen, and there will not be any client side validation on the form, so after i submit the form i will get an error that the column is required,,, but in my case i want the checbox to be conditionally required using JavaScript...which is not working

Comment: @johnG You should have put all that background information in your question at the beginning. Anyway, I don't understand. You say you want the checkbox to be conditionnaly required using Javascript, and in my snippet that's the javascript which adds the `required` property on the `checkbox`. So that's client-side. If there are some instructions we cannot use, please tell us.

Comment: now there is not any instructions,, but i mean even when the required property is being set on the checkbox, i am able to submit the form without checking the checkbox... i am not saying there is any restriction, i am saying that this appraoch is not working on the ERP system..

Comment: @johnG Do you already have some JS working on the ERP? If yes, can you try to put the `disabled` property on the `submit`? Then, tell me if it does disable it, and I'll propose another solution.

Comment: @johnG Do you *need* jQuery to achieve this? Is there already some working jQuery on your ERP clients?