# Unable to Mute HTML5 video using jQuery attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to mute video using `attr` but it doesn't work.

HTML

```
 <video autoplay muted class='preview-video'>
       <source src='file.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
 </video>
```

jQuery

```
function volumeToggle(button) {
    var muted = $(".preview-video").attr("muted");
    $(".preview-video").attr("muted", !muted)
}
```

However, when I try `prop()` instead of `attr()` it works. Can someone explain in detail the reason behind it?

Comment: .attr does not trigger events

Comment: See the Attributes vs. Properties section in [jQuery's documentation for `attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: @HereticMonkey no it does not

Comment: The answers to that question explain, in detail, the differences between `prop()` and `attr()` and how they work. Your question is how `prop()` and `attr()` work  I'm not sure how it couldn't answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to toggle the `muted` *property* of the `video` element, not the *attribute*. Try this:

```js
let $vid = $('.preview-video');

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $vid.prop('muted', (i, m) => !m);
});
```

```css
video {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle Mute</button>
<video autoplay muted class='preview-video'>
  <source src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: OP want to have explanation about why `.props()` works and `.attr()` don't

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/258469/519413 & https://lucybain.com/blog/2014/attribute-vs-property/