# Getting href value in HTML without resolution of URL

Tags: javascript, html

I have a static HTML that I generate using a script.

My hyperlinks in the HTML look like this:

`<a href="corners/xyz.csv">Data</a>`

They corners directory is present in the same directory where the HTML resides. When I open this using my browser, the browser resolves the URL which becomes something like:

`/home/user/blah/blah1/corners/xyz.csv`

I want to use the href value in some part of my javascript function. When I do `getElementsByTagName("a")[0]` i get the entire resolved URL.

But, all I want is `corners/xyz.csv`

Is there a way to get the text that is present in the href tag without resolving it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [Element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) function to get the value of `href` attribute. This function returns the value of the specified attribute.

```
getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute('href')
```

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href)
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute('href'))
```

```html
<a href="corners/xyz.csv">Data</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the attribute, not the property

```js
var anchor = document.querySelector("a")
console.log(anchor.getAttribute('href'))
```

```html
<a href="foo/bar.baz"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("href");`

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAtrribute("href")` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

`pathname` is the property you are looking for,

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('a').pathname);
```

```html
<a href="corners/xyz.csv">Data</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10673539/227176) I discovered that the property resolves to an absolute URL while the *attribute* remains the string value you want. In your case (since you are grabbing all the `a` tags) you would want to map them.

```
let rawHrefs = [...document.getElementsByTag('a')]
  .map(el => el.getAttribute('href'));
```