# Actual hidden properties on HTML elements - what is the correct term?

Tags: javascript, html

I've known about this for a while, but I'm not exactly sure what it's called:

```
var el = document.createElement("p");
el.innerText = "Hello";
el.loremipsum = "TEST STRING"; <-- THIS

document.body.appendChild(el);
```

If I inspect the DOM, this is what I get:

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

The `loremipsum` property is not in the DOM, but:

```
document.querySelector("p").loremipsum
```

returns "TEST STRING". What is this property manipulation called? I would like to research it a bit. And yes, I know data attributes are better to use.

Comment: It's a "custom property". But it's not hidden from the DOM, you can find it from the listing. It's just not reflected to the attributes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/258469/1625737

Comment: @Teemu Gotcha, so it's a custom property. Good to know. Thanks.